# Quickest way to search txt/bin/etc file for numeric data greater than specified value

Tags: matlab, file, search

I have a 37,000,000x1 double array saved in a matfile under a structure labelled r. I can point to this file using matfile(...) then just use the find(...) command to find all values above a threshold val

This finds all the values greater than/equal to 0.004 but given the size of my data, this takes some time.

I want to reduce the time and have considered using bin files (apparently they are better than txt files in terms of not losing precision?) etc, however I'm not knowledgable with the syntax/method

I've managed to save the data into the bin file, but what is the *quickest* way to search through this large file?
The only output data I want are the actually values greater than my specified value.

IS using a bin file the best? Or a matfile? Etc

I don't want to load the entire file into matlab. I want to conserve the matlab memory as other programs may need the space and I don't want memory errors again

Comment: `37e6 * 8bytes = ~300mb` doesn't look like a big problem to me. Also, you can always load the file, and retain the logical vector alone which would be only ~40mb, and clear the loaded variable. I reckon your problems lie else.

Comment: If you have to do find value above a threshold often, whether you want to save in `.mat` or `.bin`, consider spending the time (once) to sort your array ... All your next search of a threshold will be a lot faster as you won't have to browse the file completely every time.

Comment: @Hoki. The array is a correlation function for an audio file (the order matters). I could sort the array, but I'm guessing if have to create another array to hold their indexes which will probably take longer to do

Comment: @Oleg, as I mentioned to horchler, while the file may seem small, even a simple command like plot(m.r) produces a memory error. I very much would not like to load in a variable to prevent problems like this. This is the reason why I've decided to save my data outside Matlab, in Mat files, text files, etc. The down side however it that it takes some time, and I'm wondering what are the quickest options I have, knowing this

Comment: Plotting will always use much more memory than it takes to keep in the workspace. Also, what's the point of plotting 37e6 points when you only have thousands of pixels...

Comment: The plots allow you to zoom in. You might not be able to see every plot point at the same time but you can still see every individual point. With the data stored in the mat file and not matlab I can plot the data, but the point is I was just wondering if there are quicker ways to search through for values greater than a specified value. I can use mat files, and I want to check how fast txt/bin files are but I'm not quite sure how to go about writing this program. You have various commands such as fread/textscan etc

Comment: I just do not recommend to plot the whole thing. Load all data, save positions to problematic points, plot only some neighborhood of the points u want to inspect.

Keep in mind that visual data inspection with that many data points is a limited approach of investigation and should be used to get a feel of the data, not a complete understanding.

Comment: What I mean by my answers is that I do not think the whole process of coding alternatives ways of I/O and doing the data processing will save you time.

Answer (score 1):

As @OlegKomarov points out, a 37,000,000 element array of doubles is not very big.  Your real problem may be that you don't have enough RAM and/or are using a 32-bit version of Matlab. The `find` function will require additional memory for the input and the out array of indices.

If you want to load and process your data in chunks, you can use the [`matfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) function. Here's a small example:

```
fname = [tempname '.mat'];                 % Use temp directory file for example
matObj = matfile(fname,'Writable',true);   % Create MAT-file
matObj.r = rand(37e4,1e2);                 % Write random date to r variable in file

szR = size(matObj,'r');                    % Get dimensions of r variable in file
idx  = [];
for i = 1:szR(2)
    idx = [idx;find(matObj.r(:,i)>0.999)]; % Find indices of r greater than 0.999
end
delete(fname);                             % Delete example file
```

This will save you memory, but it definitely not faster than storing everything in memory and calling `find` once. File access is always slower (though it will help a bit if you have an SSD). The code above uses dynamic memory allocation for the `idx` variable, but the memory is only re-allocated a few times in large chunks, which can be quite fast in current versions of Matlab.

Comment: I'm using matfile currently, and it works, but I was wondering whether the time could be reduced by using another method. Also, I know that the file is relatively small in size but I will still get issues with memory. For example I merely tried to run plot(m.r) and I got a memory error. The workspace only had the m variable